# SwiftUI. App crashes on iPad with iOS 13.4-13.7 when long-pressed

Tags: ios, ipad, swiftui, drag, ios13.4

It's my first question on stackoverflow. Please correct me if I wrong with formatting topic.

I get crash of application when try use **long press** (?haptic touch?) on real iPad. Also it's reproducible on Simulators iPad with Force Touch click on Magic Trackpad.

#### Which devices have this bug?

Every iPad since **iOS 13.4** until the last iOS 13.
Every Simulator iPad since iOS 13.4 until the last iOS 13.

I never saw this bug on iPhone.

My set up for testing: MacOS Catalina 10.15.6, **xCode 11.7**,
Simulator iPad mini 2019 5-gen iOS 13.7,
iPad 2018 6-gen iOS 13.7.

**Upd 26.10.2020**. Also, I try to use **xCode 12.0.1** on MacOS Catalina 10.15.7,
iPad 2018 6-gen iOS 13.7. I retested, looks like the bug still available on **iOS 13.4-13.7**, but is gone for **iOS 14**. Good decision for iOS 13 I didn't find.

#### Steps to reproduce the bug.

1. I use SwiftUI view (`TestCrashIPAD`) with List, ForEach and dynamic sections (source code below).
2. Some static sections are predefined, some dynamic sections appear after fetching from server.
3. **IMPORTANT** the bug reproducible only when first appear view! Don't go to another screen or minimize the app!
4. Just open this view (`TestCrashIPAD`).
5. Wait until dynamic sections appers.
6. As soon as the sections appear, try long-press [on the cell with text "r1" or "r2" or ... (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM2Ul.png)
7. [Get crash (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZOPl.jpg)

#### CRASH

I get crash on AppDelegate with:
`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

I investigated a little bit, and found: this bug reproducible since iOS 13.4. Also with iOS 13.4 there is a [View Modifier onDrag (link)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/ondrag(_:)). May be it's somehow connected, because in call stack I see:

```
UIDragInteractionLongPressDriver
UIGestureRecognizer
```

May be something wrong with dynamic sections array, because I see:

```
SwiftUI.Sections.rowIDs(forSectionAt: Swift.Int)
SwiftUI.ListCoreDataSource.rowIndex(at: Foundation.IndexPath)
```

#### Question

How to fix this issue? How to work around without crash in this case? Please, say any idea.

#### Source Code

Please have a look the source code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestCrashIPAD: View {

    @State var sections = [TestSection]()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            // predefined sections
            Section(header: Text("Section predefined")) {
                Text("1")
                Text("2")
            }
            Section(header: Text("Section predefined")) {
                ForEach(1..<7) {
                    Text("\($0)")
                }
            }

            // dynamic content
            ForEach(sections) { section in
                Section(header: Text(section.title)) {
                    ForEach(section.rows) { row in
                        HStack {
                            Text(row.str)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        .navigationBarTitle("iPad crash with long press")
        .onAppear(perform: onAppearAction)
    }

    func onAppearAction() {

        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            // fetch some data from the server
            sleep(3)

            // show data in UI
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.sections = [TestSection](TestSection.array)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestSection: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let rows: [TestRow]

    static var array: [TestSection] {
        var result = [TestSection]()
        for idx in 0..<50 {
            result.append(TestSection(title: "s\(idx)", rows: TestRow.array))
        }
        return result
    }
}

struct TestRow: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let str: String

    static var array: [TestRow] {
        var result = [TestRow]()
        for idx in 0..<Int.random(in: 3..<7) {
            result.append(TestRow(str: "r\(idx)"))
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: We were having this same crash. Adding a `.onLongPressGesture {}` on the view in the foreach seemed to fix it for us.

Comment: @mikemike396, it helps in xCode 12 with iOS 13.7 on iPad 2018 (6-Gen). Which version do you use: xCode 11 or 12 ?

Comment: We are using Xcode 12

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer is to add `.onLongPressGesture { }` to your lists that are crashing
(i got this from comments, but this resolved my issues, so seems like an answer. posting as an answer bc not everyone reads comments